# How can I use ftp://user:pw@host/... style urls in the wiki?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

When defining a link like this

```
[description](ftp://user:pw@host/...)
```

or simply

```
ftp://user:pw@host/...
```

Azure DevOps turns the colon between user and pw into a slash. In other words, the effective user name when clicking the link will be `user/pw`, with no password set.

Is there a way to prevent AzDO from doing that?

As a workaround, I'm now using backticks:

```
`ftp://user:pw@host/...`
```

which keeps the url unchanged, but a) it is not turned into a clickable link and b) I cannot use a description text to be displayed in place of the link.

**Update**: What I'm trying to do is [fine](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%5Bdescription%5D(ftp://user:pw@host/...)) according to [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/), an attempt to create an unambiguous specification of Markdown, that has been adopted by the likes of GitHub and StackOverflow:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**>>By reference to this doc: [About Wikis, READMEs, and Markdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/about-readme-wiki?view=azure-devops), wiki uses [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) format.

Testing in [Markdown online](https://markdownlivepreview.com/) and found that this
`[description](ftp://user:pw@host/...)` will show link content `ftp://user:pw@host/...`. However, it shows `ftp://user/pw@host/...` in Azure DevOps wiki page, so this issue can be reproduced.

It might be caused by Azure DevOps security consideration, I suggest that you could submit this issue [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem), so the product group will investigate it further. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. Reading your answer, I tried to verify if this is indeed an issue affecting Markdown in general. According to CommonMark however this does not seem to be the case (see the edit to my question), so it would be great if you could elaborate on the mentioned Markdown limitation, or provide a link.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please check my updated answer.